Next.js App Router Metadata - Generate canonical URL and meta `alternates` languages
In a Next.js multi-language app, I have set a metadataBase and the alternates#canonical is automatically populated with the current route's pathname by using ./.
export const metadata = {
  metadataBase: new URL(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_BASE_URL),
  alternates: {
    canonical: "./"
  }
}

I also want to generate metadata alternates#languages.
From the docs, I found
alternates: {
  canonical: './',
  languages: {
    'en': '/en',
    'fr': '/fr',
  },
},

But it produces the following output:
eg:
default language: https://acme.com/salaries
en: https://acme.com/en/
fr: https://acme.com/fr/
Notice that the current pathname is missing from alternate languages.
What I want to achieve is to add a locale prefix to the pathname ./ resolves to.
eg:
default language: https://acme.com/salaries
en: https://acme.com/en/salaries
fr: https://acme.com/fr/salaries

You can provide them at the page.tsx level

This should dynamically append the current path (/salaries) to the canonical and alternate URLs, making sure that the alternates reflect the full route. this method should work for Next.js 14 to dynamically adjust alternate urls, based on the current route and locale.
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  const currentPath = params?.slug ? `/${params.slug}` : '';

  return {
    alternates: {
      canonical: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_BASE_URL}${currentPath}`,
      languages: {
        en: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_BASE_URL}/en${currentPath}`,
        fr: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_BASE_URL}/fr${currentPath}`,
      },
    },
  };
}



I didn't found anything wiht x-invoke-pathname. Did you mean x-invoke-path?

yes i meant x-invoke-path.

To achieve the desired functionality where the alternate language links include the current pathname with the locale prefix, u need to dynamically generate the URLs based on the current route. u can do this in a next.js multi-language app:

Dynamic Metadata Generation: create a helper function to generate the alternate URLs dynamically based on the current route and the supported languages.
Access the Current Path: u may need to access the current path in a way that works both on the server and the client.
Combine Metadata with Generated URLs: combine the generated URLs with the metadata configuration.

